# Redux: How to create state based on other state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I´m trying to learn Redux, so: I'm going through Action creators, actions, reducers, dispatchers...

Now, I´m trying to learn how to generate x-state based on other states. For the case, names and hobbies.

I've the types, const: `NAMES` and `HOBBIES` which are used by my action creators which return them as type and a payload, example: { type: HOBBIES, request: payload }

Then I have my reducer file where I switch by an action for both cases (and the default one)

I dispatch from my main file, App.js and access to those states as props.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    names: state.names,
    hobbies: state.hobbies
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ grabNames, grabHobbies }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(myApp);
```

I´m using combineReducers (index.js)

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  names: namereducer,
  hobbies: hobbyreducer
});
```

Currently I have the following redux State.

```
names: [
  {name: "A", id: "1"},
  {name: "B", id: "2"},
  {name: "C", id: "3"}
]
```

and

```
hobbies: [
  {basedId: "1", hobby: "cooking"},
  {basedId: "2" hobby: "reading"},
  {basedId: "3" hobby: "gaming"},
{basedId: "1" hobby: "reading"}
]
```

The result should be an array of objects containing the hobby for each `basedId`, following of course the good practices of Redux.

```
result: [
      {name: "A", id: "1", hobby: ["cooking", "reading"]},
      {name: "B", id: "2", hobby: "reading"},
      {name: "C", id: "3", hobby: "gaming"}
]
```

The thing is that I never went beyond simple maps and [...state, action.data];

I tried to find a solution to this but I could not. I really appreciate any help as I'm quite new.

Comment: As long as a "hobby" consists of only a string, consider maintaining this 1:N relation (one person has many hobbies) by simply keeping them in an array inside the names reducer. Only when a "hobby" becomes a more complex object with other properties (which you don't want to duplicate in `state.names` obviously) you need to establish this mapping with a library like `reselect`. mapStateToProps also works fine without it btw, it's just an optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect). Your code will basically look like this:

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const namesSelector = state => state.names;
const hobbiesSelector = state => state.hobbies;
const combineNamesAndHobbies = (names, hobbies) =>
  names.map(name => ({
    ...name,
    hobby: hobbies.filter(hobby => hobby.basedId === name.id)
                  .map(hobby => hobby.hobby)
  }));

const resultSelector = createSelector(
  [namesSelector, hobbiesSelector],
  combineNamesAndHobbies
);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    names: namesSelector(state),
    hobbies: hobbiesSelector(state),
    result: resultSelector(state)
  }
}
```

This will result in your `myApp` component having these `props`:

```js
{
  names: [
    { name: "A", id: "1" },
    { name: "B", id: "2" },
    { name: "C", id: "3" }
  ],
  hobbies: [
    { basedId: "1", hobby: "cooking" },
    { basedId: "2", hobby: "reading" },
    { basedId: "3", hobby: "gaming" },
    { basedId: "1", hobby: "reading" }
  ],
  result: [
    { name: "A", id: "1", hobby: ["cooking", "reading"] },
    { name: "B", id: "2", hobby: ["reading"] },
    { name: "C", id: "3", hobby: ["gaming"] }
  ]
}
```

Note that `hobby` will always be an array, which I'd consider best practice. (But you should name it `hobbies` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

One of the redux principle is "Single source of truth".
it means do not duplicate data, its more efficient and prevents many bugs and problems.

But if you just want to share data between two reducers you can do 
by usingusing [redux thunk middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk)

Basically you can read data from other reducers states before the action is launched with the dispatch.

**Simple action**:

```
function myAction() {
  return {
    type: DO_SOMTHING
  };
}
```

**Action with thunk**

```
function myAction() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    // get state contains all existing reducers states
    const { reducerTwo } = getState(); 

    dispatch({
      type: DO_SOMTHING,
      data: reducerTwo.prop
     });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue not to generate a new state out of your already stored data, since you would be storing the same (but modified) data twice. Rather perform this data manipulation and construct your `result` object when you need it.

Having said that, here's your answer with a bit of **ES6** spice:

```
names.map(name => (
   { ...name, hobby: hobbies.filter(hobby => hobby.basedId === name.id).map(hobby => hobby.hobby) } 
))
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @xehpuk. By using [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) you avoid recomputing the generated state if none of the related state changes, useful if the selector function is called a lot of times, like in a render loop, so you don't need to manually optimize this part.

To reduce the code needed you can also try [redux-named-reducers](https://github.com/mileschristian/redux-named-reducers) and write the selector like this instead:

```
const resultSelector = createSelector(
  [namesModule.names, hobbiesModule.hobbies],
  combineNamesAndHobbies
);
```

This adds a little overhead computation in exchange for the shortcut